# Enstrophy and energy spectral density of vorticity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I'm processing some flow field data obtained by PIV for a turbulent jet with the intention of using the energy spectral density (ESD) function to say something about the processes going on.  I'm calculating ESDs for both my velocity and (2D) vorticity.  Am I right in thinking that the latter is basically the enstrophy transfer function?  That is
$$\mathcal{E}(\kappa) = \mathcal{F}_{\kappa} \{ \left< \omega(x)\omega(x+r) \right>\} \sim \text{Enstrophy} $$

$\mathcal{F}_\kappa\{\cdot\}$ is the fourier transform and $\left< \omega(x)\omega(x+r) \right>$ is the autocorrelation of the vorticity, $\omega$.

Comment: More on enstrophy: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+enstrophy

Answer (score 1):

Enstrophy is defined as $\Omega = (1/2)\langle |\omega|^2\rangle$. The $\mathcal{E}(k)$ in your question is not the same as enstrophy.

Enstrophy is the analog of kinetic energy density, except that the velocity in the latter is replaced by vorticity in the former.

Comment: I understand the difference in definition but it seems to me that $\mathcal{E}(\kappa)$ is similar to the enstrophy contained at scale $\kappa$.